How to use command "org.eclipse.ui.file.import" in Application.e4xmi?
I am migrating my RCP application from Eclipse 3.x to Eclipse 4.
My application has org.eclipse.ui.exportWizards extension point declared in plugin.xml.
In Eclipse 3.x, I can declare an item in File menu, with command ID org.eclipse.ui.file.export and when I click in this item, Eclipse open the export wizard with my item.
In Eclipse 4, I try to define a command in Application.e4xmi with the same ID, and add the item to menu. The menu has the item, but it is disabled. I imagine that this happens because I did not declare a handler for the commmand.
Is there a way to reuse this command from Eclipse, or I will have to implement my handler to open the export wizard manually?

If you are still using the org.eclipse.ui.xxx plug-ins (such as the Export wizard) and all the workspace resource APIs you should stick to the 3.x compatability code, moving things to the Application.e4xmi for those is tricky and doesn't really give you any advantages.

Thanks for the answer.
My idea was to migrate my application to Eclipse 4 completely. But apparently, not everything was migrated to the "Eclipse 4 way". So, for some things, I either review the implementation, or continue depending on the org.eclipse.ui package. Right?

A "pure" e4 RCP only uses plug-ins in the org.eclipse.e4.rcp feature, this excludes all org.eclipse.ui.xxx plugins and the resources APIs such as IFile. If you have an existing RCP using those things it may be a lot of work to convert. I have several RCPs written as pure e4 but they were designed that way from the start.

I understand. Thank you.
